# Android - Convert file path to uri (not working)

Tags: java, android, file

i want to convert a file path to a uri. but i get errors saying it can't resolve the uri. The image come from saving an image from a camera intent. the image is saved to this directory: getFilesDir(); which is in the app.

in my cursor adapter:

```
String imgPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_IMG_PATH ));
        String productName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME ));
        int productStock = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_STOCK ));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID )));
        File imgFile = new File(imgPath);
        Uri imgURI = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);

        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            Log.v("image file" , String.valueOf(imgFile));
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            productImage.setImageURI(imgURI);
            Log.v("Image does exist", "file | " + String.valueOf(imgURI));
        }
        else {
            Log.v("bitmap --- ", "Could not find file | " + imgPath);
        }
```

one of the error lines:

```
W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///data/user/0/com.example.android.inventoryapp/files/JPEG_20170710_094130_1552703275.jpg
```

Comment: Do not use `setImageURI()`. That will load the image on the main application thread, which will freeze your UI for a while. Use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso), giving the library your `File` object.

Comment: i found a solution, thanks!

Comment: it is a project from Udacity.com and the criteria forbids external libraries/frameworks.

Comment: I cannot recommend that Udacity course, then. This is the sort of thing that will haunt you in interviews, code reviews, etc.

Comment: i agree that there are cons to that criteria. they say that the purpose is to get familiar with raw java but why re-invent the wheel. albeit i still think the course overall is good. it's called: Android basics by google nanodegree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this below code

```
 Uri uri =   Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for the help. I found a solution. The filepath was good but it was an empty file, i think. I had to write to it like this:

```
private File createImageFile(Bitmap image) throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File directory = this.getFilesDir();

        // Save Bitmap
        this.photo = new File(directory, imageFileName + ".jpg");
        this.photo.createNewFile();
        // Write to/Compress the Bitmap from the camera intent to the file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.photo);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();

        // path to file
        this.imgPath = this.photo.getAbsolutePath();
        return this.photo;
    }
```